# Generate classes with gradle and jaxb for tests with different configuration

Tags: testing, gradle, jaxb, xjc

I'm using

```
id "com.bmuschko.docker-java-application" version "3.0.7"
```

https://github.com/rackerlabs/gradle-jaxb-plugin

gradle plugin and this configuration:

```
jaxb {
    xsdDir = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/xsd/"
    bindingsDir = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/xsd/"

    xjc {
        taskClassname = "org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.xjc.XJC2Task"
        args = [
                '-Xfluent-api'
        ]
    }
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += "${generatedSources}"
compileJava.dependsOn xjc
```

for tests I want to add more arguments to xjc. And run this new task with regular `gradle build` (depending the test task on this one). Maven solves this with help of executions

```
               <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.13.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>prod</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>test</id>
                            <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <generateDirectory>target/generated-test-sources/xjc</generateDirectory>
                                <addCompileSourceRoot>false</addCompileSourceRoot>
                                <addTestCompileSourceRoot>true</addTestCompileSourceRoot>
                                <args>
                                    <arg>-Xfluent-api</arg>
                                    <arg>-Xinheritance</arg>
                                    <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                                    <arg>-Xvalue-constructor</arg>
                                    <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                                    <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
                                    <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                                </args>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                        <bindingDirectory>src/main/xsd</bindingDirectory>
                        <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <readOnly>true</readOnly>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-Xfluent-api</arg>
                        </args>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

But how to solve it in gradle? I want as result 2 sets of classes in different folders - one for production code and one for tests (with additional jaxb plugins enabled).

Simple

```
task tst(type: org.openrepose.gradle.plugins.jaxb.task.JaxbXjc) {

}
```

Requires separate configuration

```
> No value has been specified for property 'bindings'.
> No value has been specified for property 'episodeDirectory'.
> No value has been specified for property 'generatedFilesDirectory'.
> No value has been specified for property 'schemasDirectory'.
> No value has been specified for property 'xsds'.
```

different from dsl. How to reuse the dsl-based configuration?

Comment: Do you only either test or build production code, or should this support doing tests and building the production stuff in one Gradle run?

Comment: Both tasks should be executed in the same run. So I should run just `gradle build` and get both sets

Comment: Then you need to define two tasks of the respective type and configure them accordingly

Comment: Yep, the question is about how to do this with this plugin

Comment: `task foo(type: JaxbXjc) ...` like usual

Comment: And it doesn't work - `Could not get unknown property 'JaxbXjc' for project ':myprj' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148090/discussion-between-lanwen-and-vampire).

Comment: Of course you need to either use the fully-qualified classname or import the class. It is `org.openrepose.gradle.plugins.jaxb.task.JaxbXjc`.

Comment: How can I reuse another task config in this case? Also, it doesn't allow same dsl.

Comment: Just set the properties of one task from the properties of the other task. Look at the docs or sources for the properties. Of course the "DSL" is different. With the DSL you talk about you configure the plugin which configures the task, not the task itself. The plugin then adds and configures the task.

Comment: Finally got `Cannot get property 'treeRoot' on null object` when all suggested properties is set... And such copy looks a little bit ugly

Comment: As  I said, look at docs of existing, or look at the sources, e. g. of the plugin on how it configures the task.